# Why was this question closed though not seeking recommendations?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66329814/how-to-store-post-data-of-a-forum-cheaply

I explicitly wrote "not seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, etc" but it was closed as "We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more."

What???

---

For example, if I ask "Which is the fastest algorithm to do ~ ?", I'm not seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, etc. It's the same thing.

---

You are contradictory. If my question is closed, then something like these must also be closed but you don't close them:

- [MySQL vs MongoDB 1000 reads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9702643/13087034)
  (Seeking recommendation)
- [Cheapest way to deploy a React app using NextJS SSR on AWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61433306/13087034)
  (A question about cost and seeking recommendation)

---

"Why don't you use X?" is a recommendation, and the question is not looking for that kind of answer. "X is the cheapest" is a fact. The question is seeking facts.

Comment: The close reason listed on the question may not quite match, but *Is there a way to store this data cheaply?* is more of a cost question than a programming problem, so it's not on-topic here (it also sounds quite broad and could be opinion-based)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Don't programmers think about cost?

Comment: Sure. Programmers think about food and housing and interpersonal relations too, but that doesn't make the topics on-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: I think the cheapest way is an interesting problem for programmers as well as the fastest algorithm.

Comment: Could you explain what kind of answer you would expect which is not a recommendation? Because I expect answers to be mostly links to cheap db provider.

Comment: Cheapest in what sense? Minimal memory use? (keeping it generally on storage and reading to memory when needed?), minimal storage use? (high memory availability? High compression?), cheapest cloud service? Cheapest RDBMS (licensing? distributed database or one machine?)?

Comment: If you're looking for an algorithm of some kind, then you should clarify that in your question. As it is, I'm not sure what you're actually asking for.

Comment: I think such questions are better answered by blogs or self-research based on costs calculation from different providers. Moreover, the question is not specific because every developer will have a different choice based on the trade-offs they have face or they give weight. If you provide a specific case which you tried and put it here then the community will be able to help better. Like you mentioned programmers care about the fastest algorithm but if we consider each sorting algorithm has its trade-offs and asking just, "Which sorting is good?" would be off-topic unless it is a specific case.

Comment: @Nick you forgot the hour rate. They can hire me, I'm cheap ...

Comment: @BDL I'm seeking fact, not recommendations. "1<2" is fact. If DB_1 costs $1 and DB_2 costs $2, DB_1 is cheaper.

Comment: @PONPON - Facts are orthogonal to recommendations. Something can be a fact and still be a recommendation. BDL asked you to present a case where an answer would not involve recommending a service (for being *cheaper*). If you ask for the cheapest DB, you will get answers with links to providers at best and shameless promotions and spam at worst. Reducing DB reads or writes with a *side-effect* of reducing costs is a valid programming question, asking for the cheapest service is not. It is a management question.

Comment: @PONPON - That might be the case, but “Is there a way to store this data cheaply?”, isn’t a question that is within scopes at Stack Overflow.  If it was a programming question about the forum software that would have been a topic within scope.  You don’t even define what “cheaply” means, for Microsoft a 500,000 a month operating cost isn’t expensive, for a startup that is expected to bring in 500,000 the entire year that’s extremely expensive

Comment: This horse is a dead one, and you'd best find another one to ride

Comment: @rene ' They can hire me, I'm cheap'....[copied to diary for future blackmail]..:)

Comment: The second example you added should actually be closed. That's pretty much the same case as your own question.

Comment: The MongoDB vs Mysql is an invalid example. Comparing two solutions for performance with proper test cases as shown in that example , is a programming task faced by developers and both the method and the results are valuable for future readers. The other example question is more an architectural one: Do I need to host on a full VM (EC2) or not. That is different from "I have lots of data, find me a storage option"

Comment: @Cerbrus I beg to differ but you'll probably win.

Comment: Ah, yea, it's more architecture than "save me money"...

Comment: @rene My question is comparing N solutions for cost performance with a case of forum.

Comment: Your determination for defending the question is admirable, but this is really grasping at straws. Comparison of DB performance is a valid programming question (just as much as it is valid to compare time complexities of algorithms). *cost* is a budgeting concern unless you are tasked to reduce DB reads to cut costs, in which the latter is a side-effect, and the question is *really* about optimization techniques. The first linked post asks for reasons why there is an unexpected speed diff, the second - can a Next.js app be deployed on AWS without EC2 which only *happens* to stem from a [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] cost concern. Frankly, it sounds a bit dishonest to attempt to throw good Q&As under the bus in a vain attempt to convince others that black is actually white. Please, answer one question: does the question "how to get pizza cheaply?" sound like a question asking about a thoughtful comparison of advantages and disadvantages of business models for pizzerias? If by "costs" you meant one of the things outlined by Nick above, please do say so - otherwise, I really fail to grasp what is "technical" about the question.

Comment: *My question is comparing N solutions for cost performance with a case of forum.* Yes, where N = 42  and the burden is on me to find the 42 options and their cost parameters.

Comment: @OlegValter Aside from the impression issue, that pizza question can be answered by a fact. "This is the cheapest way to get a pizza." is a fact, as is "1 is the smallest natural number". I didn't know that the English word "cost" means something like memory use, storage use, etc. I am asking about the amount of money needed to maintain the service.

Comment: @PONPON - we are not trying to convince you the question is not factual. We are only trying to get through to you that this is not a programming question and was appropriately closed as seeking recommendations as it explicitly requests answerers to go fetch a list of services with prices. When I choose between an array, a `Map`, or a `Set`, I am solving a programming problem, when putting up a price breakdown of mailing services for a client - a business one. SO is not a business advice platform. If you'd wanted to find a solution that could *handle* 2M posts a day, that would be on-topic.

Comment: There are also intangibles beyond just storage costs. Migrations, upgrades, maintenance etc. Nobody can address those for you in a simple answer as they would know nothing about your developer(s) capabilities. Those issues also lead into another close reason..."opinion"

Comment: @OlegValter Not recommendations. "Why don't you use X?" is a recommendation, and I am not looking for that kind of answer. "X is the cheapest" is a fact. The question is seeking facts.

Comment: In the time you have spent on this meta post and the comments you could have run the Azure, AWS and Google calculators to find that "fact" yourself. We're not going to recommend you an external resource based on your requirements, facts or not.

Comment: Based on this I would very much like to add cost-related topics specifically to the top-level list of off-topic reasons rather than it falling in the "and more" part. It is true that many people face this question. It is also true that everyone needs to answer it for themselves rather than outsource the responsibility. If you want to define cost only in money then that's your choice, but I would not ignore the more important topics such as uptime/availability, performance, security and maintenance, backups, etc. etc.

Comment: @PONPON - I am starting to think there is a language barrier here. "Seeking recommendations" does not mean being opinion-based (I can't spell it out clearer than that...). Answers for such questions can (and maybe will) be fact-based (if we put the broadness of the "cheap" term aside, that is). That doesn't mean they are welcomed here - at best, the question treats SO as a human-powered cost calculator. It leaves no lasting value as well - in a year's time, the info will be outdated.

Answer (score 16):

I read the question as asking for recommendations for where to buy hosting (and buy/get all the other components needed to have a forum, such as a programming language/software and database). This is off topic, no matter how many restrictions or conditions come with it, and the first sentence of the message makes this clear:

> We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more.

(Specifically, it would fall under “tool” or “and more”, where “and more” is more clearly defined as [some “off-site resource”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).)

The latter part of the close reason (“You can edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations.”) is intended for questions that can be changed to not be asking for recommendations. For example, “library that does X” can sometimes become “how to X” without being too broad.

I see no way to make your question on topic (at least not while still considering it the same question). Your question would also not be on topic in its current state on SE sites that do have “recommendations” in the title.

Comment: > '“and more” is more clearly defined as “some external resource”' 
Where? Please include a URL.

Comment: @PONPON Sure! I changed that part into a direct quote.

Comment: The question is related to off-site resource, but it is not seeking recommendations. It is seeking a fact.

Comment: @PONPON all off-site resources are facts. There is no opinion involved in what the URL to get some library is or what the name of a specific book is. Doesn't make asking for a library, a book, *or other off-site sources* on-topic.